# Parametrizing rig in pose mode

Tags: rigging, bones, pose-mode

Probably very simple question, but could not find any answer by googling.
I know there are shape keys to parametrize mesh. For example imported DAZ models have shape keys for gripped/relaxed first. I also know there is an asset library now in Blender.

But is there a way to parametrize bones with a slider, like in shape key (and preferably put all of the sliders on side bar of viewport, like with imported DAZ.
I'm aware that what I want to do is commonly achieved through IK/FK and restraints, but they are mostly controlled by objects in viewport. An I'd like to have a bunch of sliders to control my rig in pose mode. Is it possible at all? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Post updated**

Mostly, what I wanted is described in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_197jQFh22E

The idea is having properties accessible on for whole `Pose Mode` for given object (not just when specific bone is selected). That is achieved with plugin ["Space Switcher"](https://gitlab.com/AquaticNightmare/space_switcher/-/tree/master), that allows to choose bone for storing custom properties and displaying them for whole `Pose Mode`. In video name "PROPERTIES" is used.

You can create custom properties in `Properties` editor → `Bone data` Tab → `Custom Properties` panel, as shown on picture below. This must be done in `Pose Mode`:

[image]

To make drivers creation easy, you can <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> a property value of a bone in the sidebar → Copy as new driver.
Then <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> the driven value → Paste as driver.

It will automatically set the driver with correct targets and settings, all you are left to do is adjusting its influence curve via <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> the driven value → Open Drivers Editor.

[image: demo of copy-pasting drivers]

Comment: [It does work in 3.1](https://i.imgur.com/OmWdJJF.jpeg) and doesn't require any script to make it work. Make sure you added the custom property from the bone data panel, not the armature nor object data panel, and be in Pose mode. The video explains further why in the `Rig custom properties` chapter.

Comment: @L0Lock I did exactly that. Unless I've missed some other checkmark, that needed to be checked, It does not work. there are bunch of comments, stating it does not work for them too. I don't even have the tab "Rig Properties". Even on your screenshots there is no such thing and properties disappear as soon as other bone is focused. Author of the video himself admitted that scripting is needed to achieve that. So your edit of my answer is incorrect (though you made it better in terms of presentation

Comment: I've returned the script snippet with some updates, since without it answer is not full. Also thanks for mentioning `Copy as new driver` I did not know about that technic.

Comment: There is no scripting ever required to display a bone's custom properties on the sidebar, that simply works if you add custom properties on the BONE DATA. Your screenshot shows you added them on the ARMATURE DATA, which doesn't work. You can make it work using scripts, but that's a convoluted solution and doesn't solve the issue that you will animate your properties in the wrong action and data block.

Comment: Now what Pierrick posted in his video's description, is that the Rig Properties panel that constantly displays all custom properties of any bone named `PROPERTIES' is actually a feature from the third party addon [Space Switcher](https://gitlab.com/AquaticNightmare/space_switcher/-/tree/master).

Comment: So either you use that addon, and then you can make a PROPERTIES bone that holds all the custom properties you want to see at all time, or you just put custom properties on any bone you want and will be required to select them to set the properties. And most likely the best solution is to do both, to avoid clutter. But in any case: you MUST put the custom properties on the BONES DATA. Not the object's, nor the armature's.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/IN3UUiB.jpeg

Comment: @L0Lock Why Adding them on ARMATURE DATA is wrong? it works for drivers and for at least make more sense to host custom properties there, since it hosts all bones

Comment: Basically, what I've done is created similar addon (because blind ad did not notice  Space Switcher in description), but without any need to create special bone for that purposes

Comment: Proof that it works: https://prnt.sc/sFnO2uEUPCmN

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138642/discussion-between-leonid-and-l0lock).

Comment: TL;DR I updated my answer to more convenient approach, using addon